# Primefaces BarChart (CartesianChartModel): DataItemValues not shown on mouseover

Tags: primefaces

I am on primefaces 3.0.M2-SNAPSHOT

Things work nicely with primefaces. Thanks very much for all your efforts!

I am trying to introduce some Charts to my App. Charts are loaded and displyed ok.
However, (using the data and code from ShowCase) when hovering over the charts, the values are not displayed (yet the color of the item does change). This is the case for pieCharts and barCharts I have tested so far. I have also tried inside/outside of layoutUnits, panels etc.. but with no success. Result is the same.

Anybody having the same problems? Reading throw the new documentation just released last week, I am not getting any wiser. Any hints on this?

Thanks.

Comment: You can edit your question to add the server, and also would be great to add some code! Though it would be wiser to update to Primefaces 3.0.M4...I really don't understand why someone would prefer a unstable version over an improved/more stable one

Comment: If you have found the solution (stupid or not stupid), you should post it here - add an answer and then accept it: this way you help the community, the same community that is willing to help you!

Comment: Will do. No luck so far. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So that means you don't want help, since I asked you to put some code and you haven't said anything!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for asking. Well the code, as per my description, is identical to the primefaces showcase (both xhtml and bean). So not much point to copy/paste the code that is on the showcase, right? As to upgrading to Version M4, I have tried M3 and that messes up my GUI prett badly, so I try to stick with what I have for the moment. I am generally wondering if my Chart issue is something others experience as well. Again, tx for asking.

Comment: If in showcase works (there is used RC1-SnapShot:same with M4) that means either you are doing something wrong, or there is a M2 bug and that still means you have to upgrade...it's up to you!